# how to pivot with django pandas using foreign keys

Tags: python, django, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I am using django-panda to make a dynamic table and I have achieved it, the problem I have is that I would like to add more rows to the table using foreign key relationships, in the [documentation](https://django-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it says: "to span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields in models, separated by double underscores, "however this does not work with to_pivot_table. I did a test with to_dataframe and here the logic if it gives results, but what I need is to implement it in the pivot

these are my models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,related_name='student')
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_students')

    def get_unanswered_questions(self, quiz):
        answered_questions = self.quiz_answers \
            .filter(answer__question__quiz=quiz) \
            .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
        questions = quiz.questions.exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).order_by('text')
        return questions

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class TakenQuiz(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes',verbose_name='Examen')
    score = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = DataFrameManager()
```

and my views

```
class ResultadosTotales(ListView):

     def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        examen=TakenQuiz.objects.all()
        qs=TakenQuiz.objects.all() 
      
        df2=taken.to_dataframe(['student__user__first_name' ,'quiz', 'score'], index='student')
        print(df)  #here I did the test with the related attribute and if it works

        rows = ['student','student__user__first_name'] #Here it does not work even though the documentation uses the same logic

        rows = ['student']
        cols = ['quiz']
    

    
        print(df2)
        pt = qs.to_pivot_table(values='score', rows=rows, cols=cols,fill_value="falta")
      
        pt=pt.to_html(classes="table table-striped border")

       
        context={ 'pivot': pt
        }
    
        return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/resultados_totales.html',context )
```

espero puedan ayudarme